# What does Oliver Wendell Holmes, Jr. mean by 'continuity with the past is only a necessity'?

Tags: jurisprudence

<sub>Preface: I first encountered the bolded on p 220, *Is Eating People Wrong? Great Legal Cases and How They Shaped the World* (2011) by Allan C. Hutchinson.

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=HamEkfqdMcEC&lpg=PA185&dq=%22continuity%20with%20the%20past%20is%20only%20a%22&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q=%22continuity%20with%20the%20past%20is%20only%20a%22&f=false) p 185, *The Essential Holmes: Selections from [...] Oliver Wendell Holmes, Jr.*, edited by Richard Posner.

Original Source: *Law in Science and Science in Law*, 
12 Harvard Law Review 443 (1899).</sub>

> This process of historical explanation has been applied to the matter 
>   of our profession, especially Of recent years, with great success, and 
>   with so much eagerness, and with such a feeling that When you had 
>   true historic dogma you had the last word not only in the present but 
>   for the immediate future, that I have felt warranted heretofore in 
>   throwing out the caution that **continuity with the past is only a necessity 
>   and not a duty**. As soon as a legislature is able to imagine abolishing the 
>   requirement of a consideration for a simple contract, it is at perfect liberty to abolish it, if it thinks it wise to do so, without the slightest regard 
>   to continuity with the past. The continuity simply limits the possibilities 
>   of our imagination, and settles the terms in which we shall be compelled to think.

I do not comprehend the bolded: How is **continuity** even **a necessity** for the law, much less **a duty**? As Holmes himself states in the last sentence above, a legislature can ignore the past and create something entirely new; I also know that some activist judges can do so.

Comment: It seems to me that this is clearly a statement of Holmes's opinion.  Obviously he realizes that it is *possible* for a legislature to ignore the past, but in this passage he argues that it is not desirable or appropriate.  I don't see how one could show whether he was objectively "correct".

Comment: @NateEldredge I believe he's stating the opposite, that courts are almost slavishly following previous judgments, but "the continuity simply limits the possibilities." I think he's equating necessity with should follow past precedent, but the courts should not feel bound to it.

Comment: Full comments, for context: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1321177?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read his point as being that continuity in law may be a necessity, but it is not a duty of those who are interpreting the law to overuse continuity: black-letter law and precedent should be followed but also understood.

Thus when the law exists it should not be changed by a judge bound to follow precedent, but when there is a close question, the judge or advocate should step beyond the necessity of merely accepting precedent as showing the right result by analogy--he should understand that competing social ideas are at work and address that conflict directly in his thinking and his decision.

Page 460 of the article has a great explanation:

> My object is not so much to point out what seems to me to be fallacies
>   in particular cases as to enforce by various examples and in various
>   applications the need of scrutinizing the reasons for the rules which
>   we follow, and of not being contented with hollow forms of words
>   merely because they have been used very often and have been repeated
>   from one end of the union to the other. We must think things not
>   words, or at least we must constantly translate our words into the
>   facts for which they stand, if we are to keep to the real and the
>   true. I sometimes tell students that the law schools pursue an
>   inspirational combined with a logical method, that is, the postulates
>   are taken for granted upon authority without inquiry into their worth,
>   and then logic is used as the only tool to develop the results. It is
>   a necessary method for the purpose of teaching dogma. But inasmuch as
>   the real justification of a rule of law, if there be one, is that it
>   helps to bring about a social end which we desire, it is no less
>   necessary that those who make and develop the law should have those
>   ends articulately in their minds. I do not expect or think it
>   desirable that the judges should undertake to renovate the law. That
>   is not their province. Indeed precisely because I believe that the
>   world would be just as well off if it lived under laws that differed
>   from ours in many ways, and because I believe that the claim of our
>   especial code to respect is simply that it exists, that it is the one
>   to which we have become accustomed, and not that it represents an
>   eternal principle, I am slow to consent to overruling a precedent, and
>   think that our most important duty is to see that the judicial duel
>   shall be fought out in the accustomed way. But I think it most
>   important to remember whenever a doubtful case arises, with certain
>   analogies on one side and other analogies on the other, that what
>   really is before us is a conflict between two social desires, each of
>   which seeks to extend its dominion over the case, and which cannot
>   both have their way.

(Thanks to cpast for the link)